# TinyMCE is blocked

Tags: tinymce

Friends,

As explained on their website, access is now blocked.

This means of course that I can no longer change any text on the pages.

I don't know what version of Tiny was used initially because the programmer left and cannot be reached.

So I registered the site and included the script at the domain level - however, to no avail. Access is still not possible.

Many thanks in advance for any help!